# How can I completely uninstall mongodb 2.6.3?

Tags: package-management, software-uninstall, mongodb

I am running the following command:

```
sudo apt-get remove mongodb
```

And it's giving this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'mongodb' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

But mongodb is still installed on my Ubuntu 13.04 system, so how can I uninstall it..?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: what's the output of `locate mongodb`?

Answer (score 40):

Try searching for installed mongo packages with `dpkg` :

```
$ sudo dpkg -l | grep mongo
```

The above command should output a list of packages with mongo in the name.

If files exist on the system, following an `apt-get remove mongo`, try and run the command again with the `--purge` switch, using a wildcard search for the name:

```
sudo apt-get remove mongodb* --purge
```

Answer (score 4):

The general methodology here should work (upvoted), but more specifically the MongoDB packages for 2.6+ (assuming you installed them from the official repos) are:

- mongodb-org (metapackage that will automatically install/remove) the four component packages below
- mongodb-org-server
- mongodb-org-client
- mongodb-org-tools
- mongodb-org-shell

Hence, if you try removing those packages you should have more success.